# Using Find & ForEach in JS Together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays called `active_filters` and `cars`. I'm working on improving performance and I'm finding that the code below is super heavy and slow. I'm wondering if it's possible to compare x.value and element[0] from cars array without having the outer forEach? I'm super new to this, so appreciate any help! If there's a better way of going about this too, I'm open to suggestions :) Thanks!!!

```
 cars.forEach(function(element) {
    active_filters.find(x => x.value === element[0].getAttribute("data-location-id"));
 });
```

**Update:**

My goal is to return whether or not the attribute data-location-id (which is located in the cars array) is located and equal to the value property in the active_filters array.

**Sample Data:**

**Active Filters Array Object**

```
{class: "data-location-id", value: "AD-48.7284-2.3601"}
{class: "data-location-id", value: "AL-48.726243-2.365247"}
```

**Cars Array:**

```
<li data-location-id="ZT-48.8308-2.3567" class="listing"></li>
<li data-location-id="AD-48.7284-2.3601" class="listing"></li>
<li data-location-id="AC-28.7284-2.3601" class="listing"></li>
```

Comment: can you provide more detail?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Some sample data would be useful.

Comment: what do expect return results ? `true/false` ?  matched car ?

Comment: I provided an update to my post. Expected results are true/false

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Hey George, for some reason your answer got removed?

Comment: @Michael He deleted it himself

Comment: Do you want a separate true/false result for each car, or one result for the whole array?

Comment: If you want to return a result for each element of the array you should be using `map`, not `forEach`.

Comment: @Barmar I'd like a separate true/false for each car

Answer (score 2):

To get a result for each element, you use `map()`, not `forEach()`. They both iterate over the array and call the function, but `forEach()` discards the result, while `map()` collects all the results into an array.

```
cars.map(car => !!active_filters.find(x => x.value === car.data("location-id")));
```

`!!` turns the result of `find()` into a boolean `true/false`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar - Quick question: How can I addClass to all cars that don't contain these values? Here's what I have so far: cars.map(car => active_filters.find(x =>
   if (car.attr(x.id) !== x.value)
    return car.addClass("filtered-out");
   ));

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to use if statement here

Comment: You need to put `{ ... }` around the body of the function if it contains a statement instead of just a simple expression. Or you can use a tertiary operator.

Comment: But there's no `id` property in your `active_filters` objects, so what is `x.id` supposed to be?

Comment: You should be using `forEach()` if you want to perform actions rather than return an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce your time complexity to linear, you can create an object with the "data-location-id" as the keys from the active_filters array. This will give you the ability to do a constant time lookup and just use a single loop instead of nested loops.

```js
const active_filters = [
  { class: "data-location-id", value: "AD-48.7284-2.3601" },
  { class: "data-location-id", value: "AL-48.726243-2.365247" }
];

// from active filters, create this active_filtersById object 
// with the value as keys for constant time lookup

const active_filtersById = {
  "AD-48.7284-2.3601": { class: "data-location-id", value: "AD-48.7284-2.3601" },
  "AL-48.726243-2.365247": { class: "data-location-id", value: "AL-48.726243-2.365247" }
}

const cars = [
  { "data-location-id": "ZT-48.8308-2.3567" },
  { "data-location-id": "AD-48.7284-2.3601" },
  { "data-location-id": "AC-28.7284-2.3601" }
];

   
const result = cars.map(car => {
  const id = car["data-location-id"];
  const isFound = active_filtersById[id];
  return isFound !== undefined;
})

console.log(result)
// result is [false, true, false]
```